# Confirmation, Printing Graphic location C#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I have created the code below to help me print the admin form as a "report" like document showing the date and graph needed for documentation.

```
  try
        {
            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
            AdminPage = new Bitmap(Size.Width, Size.Height, g);
            Graphics Printed = Graphics.FromImage(AdminPage);
            Printed.CopyFromScreen(519, 340, 0,0,this.Size);//519,340 this.Location.Y,this.Location.X
            printPreviewAdminDialogue.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch(Exception )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please check printer connection!");
        }
```

I have used the coordinate data of the screen as:

```
Printed.CopyFromScreen(519, 340, 0,0,this.Size);
```

Will this still work on any size screen or will this result in some formatting problems on other devices rather than just my laptop?

So far it looks fine [Print Preview of what i want with the current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdnBk.jpg)

Comment: Create `RDLC` report and print it.

Comment: `CreateGraphics` is almost always incorrect.

Comment: You ought to use Printed.DrawToBitmap() instead.  Right now you run the risk of the screen-shot being off if you did not declare your app to be dpiAware or getting the wrong content if another window overlaps yours.  It is also very hard to guess why you hard-coded the location instead of using this.PointToScreen(Printed.Location).  And the printout is going to look ugly due to the rescaling and inappropriate anti-aliasing, that requires a different approach.

Comment: @pink: Actually this is an exception: The Bitmap constructor can take a Graphics object to supply it with the dpi for the bitmap. So this may be perfectly fine.

Comment: The other day, I gave you one possible solution to this question. But, as I see now, it wasn't  probably *on target*, because I didn't notice that you needed a printed (controllable) version of the screen capture. Try this one other, it's more aimed to printing. A PrintPreview control can give you an immediate feedback on what it does. (Note that I will move this answer to the duplicate link you saw in your previous question).

Answer (score 0):

This method takes a Control (`SourceControl`) reference and returns a Bitmap resulting from a screen capture of the Control's Window.

**Parameters:**

**`SourceControl`**: The control to be printed. It can be a TopLevel Window (a Form) or a Child Control.

**`Dpi`**: The DPI resolution of the resulting Bitmap.

**`ScaleToDpi`**: if set to `true`, the size of the Bitmap will be scaled to match the Dpi parameter, defining a scale factor relative to current screen resolution. E.g.: If parameter `Dpi` = 300 and the current screen resolution is 96 Dpi, the resulting Bitmap size will be scaled with a factor of 3.125

**`ClientAreaOnly`**: If true, captures the `SourceControl` client area, otherwise the full window bounds.

**`InterpolationMode`**: Defines the resulting quality of a scaled bitmap. For enlargements, `Bicubic` or `HighQualityBicubic` gives better results. `Bicubic` may render a shaper image. The usefulness of this parameter depends on how the image is used. The perceived visual quality may not be the same when the image is printed on paper. When printing, sharper images give a better result.

The results can be tested using a `PrintPreviewControl` to see the difference between a scaled and a non-scaled Bitmap.

Print the a Form including its borders with a resolution of 300 DPI but not scaled to the new resolution (modifies the resulting Bitmap resolution only):

```
Bitmap FullSize300Dpi = PrintControlFromScreen(this, false, 300, false, InterpolationMode.Default);
```

Print the a Form ClientArea with a resolution of 300 DPI and scale its dimensions to the new resolution using a `HighQualityBicubic` Interpolation:

```
Bitmap ClientArea300DpiScaled = PrintControlFromScreen(this, true, 300, true, InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic);
```

The same, but it prints the client area of a `button1` control with a resolution of 96 DPI with a Bilinear Interpolation:

```
Bitmap Child96DpiUnscaled = PrintControlFromScreen(this.button1, true, 96, false, InterpolationMode.Bilinear);
```

```
public Bitmap PrintControlFromScreen(Control SourceControl, bool ClientAreaOnly, float Dpi, bool ScaleToDpi, InterpolationMode Interpolation)
{
    using (Graphics graphics = SourceControl.CreateGraphics())
    {
        SizeF ScaleFactor = new SizeF((Dpi / graphics.DpiX), (Dpi / graphics.DpiY));
        SizeF BitmapSize;

        if (ScaleToDpi)
        {
            BitmapSize = ClientAreaOnly ? new SizeF((SourceControl.ClientRectangle.Size.Width * ScaleFactor.Width),
                                                    (SourceControl.ClientRectangle.Size.Height * ScaleFactor.Height))
                                        : new SizeF((SourceControl.Bounds.Size.Width * ScaleFactor.Width),
                                                    (SourceControl.Bounds.Size.Height * ScaleFactor.Height));
        }
        else
        {
            BitmapSize = ClientAreaOnly ? SourceControl.ClientRectangle.Size : SourceControl.Bounds.Size;
        }

        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap((int)BitmapSize.Width, (int)BitmapSize.Height))
        {
            bitmap.SetResolution(ScaleFactor.Width * graphics.DpiX, ScaleFactor.Height * graphics.DpiY);

            using (Graphics ImageGraph = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                ImageGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                ImageGraph.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                ImageGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                ImageGraph.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                ImageGraph.InterpolationMode = Interpolation;

                if (ClientAreaOnly)
                {
                    ImageGraph.CopyFromScreen(SourceControl.PointToScreen(SourceControl.ClientRectangle.Location),
                                            new Point(0, 0), SourceControl.ClientRectangle.Size);
                }
                else
                {

                    if (SourceControl.TopLevelControl == SourceControl)
                    {
                        ImageGraph.CopyFromScreen(SourceControl.Bounds.Location,
                                                new Point(0, 0), SourceControl.Bounds.Size);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ImageGraph.CopyFromScreen(SourceControl.PointToScreen(SourceControl.ClientRectangle.Location),
                                                new Point(0, 0), SourceControl.Size);
                    }
                }

                if (ScaleToDpi) ImageGraph.ScaleTransform(ScaleFactor.Width, ScaleFactor.Height);
                ImageGraph.DrawImage(bitmap, new Point(0, 0));
                return (Bitmap)bitmap.Clone();
            };
        };
    };
}
```

**UPDATE1** (Example of Print Preview):

This is one possible way to show a PrintPreview of the Bitmap. It should of course be adapted to an actual Printer. This is for general use.

A Bitmap is created in a Button event handler and a PrintPreview Dialog is shown to seee the result.

> This creates a ScreenShot of a PictureBox control in the current Form
>   (this), takes the ClientArea only, sets the resuluton to 300Dpi, does
>   not scale the image (keeps the screen original size), using a Bicubic
>   Interpolation for rendering.

```
Bitmap screenCapture = PrintControlFromScreen(this.pictureBox1, true, 300, false, InterpolationMode.Bicubic);
```

This is the Button click handler from where you can call the `PrintControlFromScreen()` method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap screenCapture = PrintControlFromScreen(this.pictureBox1, true, 300, false, InterpolationMode.Bicubic);

    PrintDocument PrintDoc = new PrintDocument();
    PrintDoc.DocumentName = "ScreenShot";
    PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution = new PrinterResolution() { X = 300, Y = 300 };
    PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width < screenCapture.Width;
    PrintDoc.OriginAtMargins = true;

    PrintDoc.PrintPage += (s, ppe) =>
    {
        Rectangle BitmapSize = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0),
                               new Size(screenCapture.Width, screenCapture.Height));

        Graphics _imagegraph = Graphics.FromImage(screenCapture);
        _imagegraph.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        _imagegraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        _imagegraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        _imagegraph.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        _imagegraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        ImageAttributes ImageAttr = new ImageAttributes();
        ImageAttr.ClearThreshold(ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);

        ppe.Graphics.DrawImage(screenCapture, BitmapSize, 0F, 0F,
                               BitmapSize.Width, BitmapSize.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ImageAttr);
    };

    PrintPreviewDialog pPreviewDiag = new PrintPreviewDialog();
    pPreviewDiag.Document = PrintDoc;
    pPreviewDiag.AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(Screen.PrimaryScreen.BitsPerPixel * 1.5F,
                                                 Screen.PrimaryScreen.BitsPerPixel * 1.5F);
    pPreviewDiag.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
    pPreviewDiag.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    pPreviewDiag.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late I reply I have been busy with my Education, I would like to thank you for this help however, I would like to l know where this code belongs with mine, How would I call it to ensure it prints, would this be called from the button click or elsewhere to ensure the print preview still works

Comment: Oh, Hi!. You can print it the way you want, this method just return a Bitmap. However, I'll post an example to show how this can be done. I'll also make a couple of modifications to the method declaration, so see that you have "updated" version. If you have questions, let me know.